# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'too_long_frame_exception', 'An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes.')

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I'm working on client server so I can't edit the elasticsearch.yml file. I used ignore=400 parameter.Help me for the solution of the this error elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'too_long_frame_exception', 'An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes.').
 Here I have 928068 documents in kibana/app.

Comment: You can try to process them in smalled quantities, so the generated URL is smaller

Comment: You can look into https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html